# How to put html code for arrows in template literals

Tags: html, template-literals

I am wondering how can I put html arrows in template literals. Thank you.

```
{sort === "asc" ? `Descending ${\&#8593}`  : `Ascending ${\&#8595}`}
```

Doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0):

`${...}` is how you insert *JavaScript expressions* into template strings.

HTML is just text. Character references do need to end in a semi-colon though.

```
{sort === "asc" ? `Descending &#8593;`  : `Ascending &#8595;`}
```

There's no need to use template strings at all (since you aren't embedding JS expressions in them), you should just use a regular string.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it doesn't work. It only shows code, not an arrow.